# Saving fragments on rotation when using an Async Task

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, screen-rotation

The question pretty much sums it up, I am trying to save my fragments so when I rotate the screen the application does not crash but I am not sure where or how to save my fragments, I have tried using a fragment manager and setting retainstate to true as well as checking the saved instance state.

This is my code :
EventsActivty - Hosts the fragments

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    new AsyncLogin().execute(username, password);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    EventListFragment eventListFragment = (EventListFragment)
         EventListFragment.instantiate(this, EventListFragment.class.getName());
    EventGridFragment eventGridFragment = (EventGridFragment) 
         EventGridFragment.instantiate(this, EventGridFragment.class.getName());

    fList.add(eventListFragment);
    fList.add(eventGridFragment);

    return fList;
}
```

The getFragments is called here, on the `OnPostExecute` of the AsyncTask

```
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        try {
            getEvents(jsonObject);
            setContentView(R.layout.eventlist);
            List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
            pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
       }
```

Fragment 1 : OnCreateView

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    eventObjects = ((EventsActivity)getActivity()).getEventObjects();

    setRetainInstance(true);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventlist ,container,false);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), eventObjects));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            EventObject fullObject = (EventObject)o;
            System.out.println("asd");
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

Fragment 2:

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventgrid ,container,false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventgrid);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext())); // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity().
    return view;
}
```

Comment: You can use a service

Comment: @RogerGarzonNieto can you explain what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a `FragmentActivity` will automatically restore your fragments in `onCreate()`.

Weird thing is, you call `AsyncTask` first, prior to calling through to `super.onCreate()` and retrieving *username* and *password* from the `Intent`.

Even having set that aside, that approach will make your activity spawn a new login task every time it's rotated.

Better way is to check `savedInstanceState` for `null`:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // first launch
    new AsyncLogin().execute(username, password);
}
...
```

That way it's only going to run when `Activity` is created for the first time.

Second, you need to completely unbind login info from your activity. Make the `AsyncTask` return whatever login result you get to the `Application` and store it there. And your activity and fragments to retrieve that info from the `Application` - that way you get full control over you login procedure: you check whether there's an active session, if there isn't you check whether the `AsyncTask` is already running, if it isn't - you need to launch it. If it is - you need to wait for it to finish (show progress bar or something).

Comment: how do i get it to return the info to the application

Comment: Use static reference to `this` in your application class, singleton-style: `public static class MyApplication extends Application { public static MyApplication instance; public void onCreate() {MyApplication.instance = this} ... }`, and just get the app from your asynctask's `onPostExecute()` by referencing it, something like: `MyApplication.instance.setLoggedIn(true);` and in your `Activity` you'll do `if (!MyApplication.instance.isLoggedIn() && !MyApplication.instance.isLoginTaskRunning()) {new AsyncLogin().execute(username, password);}`

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that retaining the fragments won't prevent the activity from being distroyed.

Now take a look here:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     new AsyncLogin().execute(username, password);
     // ..... 
}
```

When a screen orientation change occurs, your activity is still destroyed. As a result a new AsyncTask is started. But when the old AsyncTask completes the job, it tries to deliver the result to the old activity, that was destroyed already. As a result this will cause a crash.

The solution would be to put the AsyncTask in the fragment itself. So that the instance to not be destroyed on orientation change.

See if [this article](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/) can help you.